# How do I write a write() method in a pkl file that I can use in my python scrpits?

Tags: python, methods, pickle

I am trying a share a boolean between different scripts. In one script, I want to edit the boolean if a certain function is called. In the other scripts, I want to use the boolean. I'm trying to use pickling, but I'm in way over my head. I have no idea what to write in my pkl file. My code kinda looks like this:

one.py

```
    import pickle

    boolean = False
    pickle.dumps(boolean, "filename.pkl")

    class Foo(object):

    #init method irrelevant

        def bar(self):
            foobar = raw_input("> ")

            if foobar == "baz":
                boolean = True
                pkl_file = open("filename.pkl", 'w')
                pickle.dumps(boolean, "filename.pkl")
            else:
                print "Hello"
```

two.py

```
    import pickle

    class Foobar(object):

    #init method irrelevant

    def foo_bar(self):
        foobar = raw_input("> ")
        boolean = pickle.loads("filename.pkl")

        if foobar == "foo" and boolean:
            print "Hi!"
        elif foobar == "foo":
            print "Hello there."
        else:
            print "Bye!"
```

I have another script that does something similar to two.py. My pkl file is empty.
When I try to run the main script (a completely different one from the ones with pickling), I get "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Thanks folks! I actually had it written in my code with dump and load, but I didn't notice the difference when I was typing my example. The advice to open the file really helped. Also to add 'r' when loading the file. It's working now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments required for `dump` and `load` need a file object, so you cannot simply pass the filename as a string. (and you should use the non-s version as mentioned by other answers)

Try something like this: `pickle.dump(boolean, open("filename.pkl", "w"))`

and `boolean = pickle.load(open("filename.pkl", "r"))`

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to use `pickle.dump(...)` and `pickle.load()`, not the string versions, like so,

```
import pickle

f = open('gherkin.pkl','w')
pickle.dump(False,f)
f.close()
g = open('gherkin.pkl','r')
print pickle.load(g)
g.close()
```

Secondly, if you open the file a second time to read it you need to set the mode to `"r"`, otherwise you're going to destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong API. The `dumps` and `loads` methods you are using are for strings, not files. (The `s` in the name stands for `string`). According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) you should be using `dump` and `load` with a file object. You should previously open the file object.